# NSString stringWithContentsOfFile persistent compiler error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {
    NSString *a;
    NSString *b;
    //NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Testimony" ofType:@"docx"];
    NSString *nameString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Testimony.docx"
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                        errro:NULL];

    NSArray *names = [nameString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    for(NSString *n in names){

        NSRange p = [n rangeOfString:@"Tobi" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        NSRange r = [n rangeOfString:@"tobi" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];


        if(p.location != NSNotFound){
            //NSLog(@"%@", n);
            a = n;
        }
        if(r.location != NSNotFound){
            //NSLog(@"%@", n);
            b = n;
        }

    }
    if([a caseInsensitiveCompare:b] == NSOrderedAscending){
        NSLog(@"a %@ comes before b %@", a, b);
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

The compiler keeps giving me "No known class method for selector" error. The word document is in the same folder as the program..I have no idea what's wrong. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [We close all the typo questions as "too localized" (formerly).](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions) The required "minimal understanding" is missing (clearly...)

Comment: This question should be removed because it is predicated on a typo and will have no usefulness for future searchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo and spelled error wrong via

> errro

```
NSString *nameString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Testimony.docx"
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                        error:NULL];
```

Comment: No problem - sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees :)